# How to swap array of characters from second array to last second array

Tags: c

Swap 2 first character to second last character and so on like 3 first character to third last character
untill character to middle of the word.

Input:

```
I love programming
```

Output:

```
i lvoe pnimmargorg
```

I tried to do

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    char s[105+t];
    getchar();
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        scanf("%[^\n]",s);
        int len  = strlen(s);
        char temp[105+t];
        getchar();
        for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++){
            strcpy(temp,s);
            s[i] = s[len-i-1];
            s[len-i-1] = temp;
        }
            for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++){
                printf("%c",s[i]);
        }
    }
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What is a "last second array"? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Oh I see, question's been vandalized to oblivion by the OP. Will try to salvage with rollback. Still not sure if this post can be saved.

Answer (score 0):

This should do for swapping

```
for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++)
{
    temp = s[i];
    s[i] = s[len-i-1];
    s[len-i-1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: s[len-i-1] = temp; is invalid , i think it must use strcpy or something but it doesnt work with strcpy

Comment: please share complete code,that works with the 1D `char` array

Comment: need more description to understand what you are doing and why, do you want a simple reverse of array or only some part of array,please add comments to your code

Comment: This swaps the first and last bytes of the word, when they should be left alone.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to approach this. The key is you want to be able to locate the beginning and end of each word in a line. (actually the 2nd and next to last character in each word). You cannot use `strtok()` or `strsep()` as both write *nul-terminating* characters in place of delimiters in your string. What you need is some way to manually advance though your line to locate the beginning and ending of each word.

One way is to use a pair of pointers and nested loops, with the outer loop advancing the start-pointer until the beginning of the next word is found. Then setting the end-pointer equal to the start-pointer and looping with a nested loop moving the end pointer until the next space or end-of-line is found. You know what lies between the two pointers will be your word.

Advance the start-pointer by one to the 2nd character and decrement the end-pointer by two to locate the next to last character (you subtract `2`, one because you currently point to the next space after the word -- to find the last char, and then subtract again for the next-to-last char)

Another option is to use `strspn()` and `strcspn()` to take the place of the nested loops. `strspn()` returns the number of left-most characters in the string made up of only characters in the *accept* parameter (use `" \t\n"` to cause it to skip over spaces to the start of the next word) and `strcspn()` which returns the left-most number of character not including the characters in the *reject* parameter. (use the same `" \t\n"` to cause it to skip over all characters in the work to the next space returning the length of the word).

Writing a simple function to apply the logic to each word in the given string and swapping from the 2nd to next-to-last character in each word could be done as:

```
char *outsidein (char *s)
{
    char *p = s;        /* pointer to position in s to work toward end */
    
    while (1) {
        size_t  offset = strspn (p, " \t\n"),               /* find 1st non-space */
                length = strcspn (p + offset, " \t\n");     /* find next space */
        if (!length)                                        /* at end, break */
            break;
        char *sp = p + offset + 1,              /* start pointer to 2nd char in word */
             *ep = p + offset + length - 2;     /* end pointer to next to last char */
        while (sp < ep) {                       /* loop toward middle */
            int tmp = *ep;                      /* swap chars at sp & ep */
            *ep-- = *sp;
            *sp++ = tmp;
        }
        p += offset + length;       /* update pointer to space following word */
    }
    
    return s;       /* for convenience, return a pointer to s for immediate use */
}
```

(**note:** the string passed as the parameter `s` must be a **mutable** string)

Above the pointer `p` is advanced down the string saving the beginning location of each word, and then the number of spaces (`offset`) and `length` is added to it to advance to the next space after the word you processed.

A short example program that puts it altogether could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

char *outsidein (char *s)
{
    char *p = s;        /* pointer to position in s to work toward end */
    
    while (1) {
        size_t  offset = strspn (p, " \t\n"),               /* find 1st non-space */
                length = strcspn (p + offset, " \t\n");     /* find next space */
        if (!length)                                        /* at end, break */
            break;
        char *sp = p + offset + 1,              /* start pointer to 2nd char in word */
             *ep = p + offset + length - 2;     /* end pointer to next to last char */
        while (sp < ep) {                       /* loop toward middle */
            int tmp = *ep;                      /* swap chars at sp & ep */
            *ep-- = *sp;
            *sp++ = tmp;
        }
        p += offset + length;       /* update pointer to space following word */
    }
    
    return s;       /* for convenience, return a pointer to s for immediate use */
}

int main (void) {
    
    char line[MAXC];
    
    while (fgets (line, MAXC, stdin)) {         /* read each line */
        line[strcspn (line, "\n")] = 0;         /* trim \n character from end */
        printf ("%s\n", outsidein (line));      /* output modified line */
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "I love programming" | ./bin/str_outsidein
I lvoe pnimmargorg
```

There are a number of ways to do it. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

That's a nice little exercise, that seems tricky at frst, but keeping it simple keeps the bugs away.

Things to look out for (aka traps for young players)

- multiple spaces between words.
- input strings that start with spaces.
- input strings that end with a space.

See comments in code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void scramble(char* str)
{
    char *p, *q, *word_start;
    char c;
    
    if (str == NULL)
        return;
    
    while (*str != 0)
    {
        // skip spaces, you could also use while (isspace(*str & 0xFF))
        // which would suddenly make this function much more 
        // versatile and interesting.  
        while (*str == ' ')
            ++str;

        // keep track of the start of the word
        word_start = str;

        // find end of word, you could also use isspace() here,
        // if you decide to go that route.
        while (*str != ' ' && *str != 0)
            ++str;
            
        // str now points to one character past the last char of word  
            
        // swap the letters we want, from second to second to last,
        // leave the others untouched.  Note that the p < q test
        // automatically skips processing of words of 3 bytes or less.
        // so this takes also care of strings ending with a space
        // which ould give us an empty word (when str == word_start)
        for (p = word_start + 1, q = str - 2; p < q; ++p, --q)
        {
            c = *p;
            *p = *q;
            *q = c;
        }
    }
}

const char input_string[] = "I love programming";

int main()
{
    char output_string[sizeof(input_string)];

    strcpy(output_string, input_string);

    printf("input:  %s\n", input_string);

    scramble(output_string);

    printf("output: %s\n", output_string);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it, and step through it: https://onlinegdb.com/SkxKerFYP